# Updating UITableView when user selects a date from calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, object

I am having some trouble trying to call my `UITableView` instead other methods.

Basically I am trying to have my code do this:

--When a user clicks on a date on the calendar, it will update the `UITableView` and populate it with a certain object (i.e Restaurant).

--I believe the code logic should go into my `(VRGCalendarView *)calendarView dateSelected` method. However I am unable to access the `tableData`.

```
#import "VRGViewController.h"

@interface VRGViewController ()

@end

@implementation VRGViewController{
    NSArray *calendarTableData;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   VRGCalendarView *calendar = [[VRGCalendarView alloc] init];
   calendar.delegate=self;
   calendar.center = self.view.center;
   [self.view addSubview:calendar];
   [self calendarTableViewData];
}

#pragma mark - Calendar Code

-(void)calendarView:(VRGCalendarView *)calendarView switchedToMonth:(int)month targetHeight:(float)targetHeight animated:(BOOL)animated {
    if (month==[[NSDate date] month]) {
      NSArray *dates = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:5], nil];
      [calendarView markDates:dates];
    }
}

-(void)calendarView:(VRGCalendarView *)calendarView dateSelected:(NSDate *)date {
    NSLog(@"Selected date = %@",date);

    **//When ever a user clicks on a data in the calendar, the date will be NSLogged. I think that my logic should go here for when a user clicks on the date it will update the tableview - however I am unable to access the tableData which is specified in another method**

   //[tableData reloadData];

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}


#pragma mark - User Defined Table View Methods

-(void)calendarTableViewData{
    calendarTableData = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict", @"Mushroom Risotto", @"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger", @"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Creme Brelee", @"White Chocolate Donut", @"Starbucks Coffee", @"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle with Egg", @"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork", @"Green Tea", @"Thai Shrimp Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake", @"Ham and Cheese Panini", nil];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
   return [calendarTableData count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"Services";
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

   if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}
    cell.textLabel.text = [calendarTableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   NSLog(@"You have selected: %@",cell.text);
}


@end
```

Comment: "However I am unable to access the tableData" can you explain more?

Comment: @anhtu, I solved the issue. The issue was that I did not assign the tableView as a `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView:` which was the cause of my issue! I will close my question thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

The issue I was having with my code was solved with some great help from the iOS community. The issue was that I populating my `UITableView` with in my `viewDidLoad()` instead of creating a `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;`